# Why angular is not compatible for every browser and their versions?

Tags: javascript, angular

After creating an angular build code is converted into javascript.

**As per the understanding:**

- Every browser understands javascript.
- A polyfill is a piece of code (usually JavaScript on the Web) used to
  provide modern functionality on older browsers that do not natively
  support it.

**Need To Understand:**

- Why there are compatibility issues of angular build on different
  browsers?
- Why Polyfills.ts is required to make it compatible on different
  browsers if it is converted to javascript?

Please correct me if i am wrong somewhere ?

Comment: This https://medium.com/hackernoon/polyfills-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-or-maybe-a-bit-less-7c8de164e423 might help you.